# How can I continue iterating within the nested for loops without iterating over a previously found value

Tags: java, arrays

The following method uses some nested loops. I have a 2D array which I have taken row 1 and made a 1D array called keys. I am now iterating across the 2D array and comparing each value from *keys* to each item in the 2D array starting with row number 2. 
So if I have the following 2D array:

```
1   1
1   0
1   0
```

upon the first iteration row 1 index 1 will compare and find that the first item in each following row is equal to the first item of row 1 (*keys*). However, when the next iteration begins since *keys* has another 1 in position 2 it will again be compared to the 1 in row 2, and this is the type of situation that I want to discriminate. The goal is to find common elements so I can't count the same element twice. I'm trying to convert my array *collections* to a 2D arraylist but was thinking it might not be necessary. What should be returned from above would be a 1D array with the values {1, null}.  Here is the method

```
public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Comparable[][] collections){
        Comparable[] keys = new Comparable[collections[0].length];
        for(int row = 0; row < 1; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < collections[row].length; column++){
                keys[column] = collections[row][column];
            }
        }


        int comparison = 0;
        Comparable[] result = new Comparable[keys.length];


        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            int found = 0;
            for(int r = 1; r < collections.length; r++){

                for(int c = 0; c < collections[r].length; c++){

                    comparison += 1;
                    if(keys[i].compareTo(collections[r][c]) == 0){

                    found += 1;
                    break;
                    }


                }
                if (found == collections.length - 1){
                result[i] = keys[i];   
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            System.out.print(result[i] + "\t");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Comparisons made: " + comparison);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what you want. Can you give example of what output you need?

Comment: Sure, so if I had a 2D array such
3  10  20
3   20  3
10  11  3

the result that would be returned would be a 1D array 
3
null
null

Comment: Are you just trying to see if the value is the same for an entire column?

Comment: no. I'm taking index 0s value from keys and comparing it to the values in the rows of the 2D array. If the value is found anywhere in the row I move to the next row. This continues to the end of keys.

Comment: Imagine a 2D array of elements in no special order with 3 rows. The first row is the key row. To find common elements I compare the items. If row 1 has 3 of the same element, for that element to be a common element 3 times it would need to appear 3 times in each of the other rows.

Comment: This may sound counter-intuitive if you've never done it this way, but have you tried writing a test case before solving your problem? Sometimes, defining _what_ you want to achieve can help you figure out _how_ to achieve it.

Comment: I have a test harness and another class which I can make work. But, it won't work for all possible cases. Say a different type than what my test is giving

Comment: So let's say that an Integer array is passed to the method, after the following line of code
if(keys[i].compareTo(collections[r][c]) == 0){

I could place the following
collections[r][c] = -1;

This would give the result I need. But at another time a String array or some other type of Comparable array could be passed, and with the above added it would return null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to find out if the entire column has alll of the same values, in which case the third nested loop is unnecesary because you just want to loop through each row but for one specific column at a time, so if you were to change it to:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        int found = 0;
        for(int r = 1; r < collections.length; r++){


                comparison += 1;
                if(keys[i].compareTo(collections[r][i]) == 0){

                found += 1;
                }
            if (found == collections.length - 1){
            result[i] = keys[i];   
            }
        }
    }
```

That should give you the result you are looking for.

If you are actually doing it differently where you are checking that a certain number exists in every row, but you only want to check it once, then you can store what has already been checked and continue if that is repeated, as follows:

```
 List<Comparable> checked = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
 outer:
 for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
 {
        for(Comparable c : list)
        {
              if(keys[i].compareTo(c) == 0) continue outer;
        }
        list.add(keys[i];
 }
```

Comment: I'm not comparing columns

Comment: Check this suggestion then.